# Bulk language assignment

Tags: i18n-l10n

In the past I created hundreds of nodes in a specific language.
Finally, the website will have only one language and I think it is best to set them all to unassigned language for development reasons.

How I can change the language in bulk?
Is there any module for that, or some SQL queries to run directly at the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Language Assign](http://drupal.org/project/languageassign) module